# symbolic link on folder created every day

Tags: symbolic-link

I've this structure

- `2011-04-18T07.32.19UTC`
- `2011-04-19T07.32.19UTC`
- `2011-04-20T03.15.01UTC`

Every night, a new directory based on the current date is created.
I would create a symbolic link on the latest directory created:

```
mysimlink --> 2011-04-20T03.15.01UTC
```

But tomorrow I would see

```
mysimlink --> 2011-04-21T03.15.01UTC
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Without knowing which operating system and how the "2011-04-21T03.15.01UTC" is being created it is difficult to offer solid advice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a script which will removes the existing symlink and then creates a new symlink pointing at the directory with today's date. Here is some code:

```
today=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

# find today's directory
todayDir=$(ls -d $today*)

# if the directory exists
if [ -d $todayDir ]
then
    rm -f mysymlink
    ln -s $todayDir mysymlink
fi
```